# Too Many Re-Renders ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

Well Im Trying To Basically Use Speech To Text With React-Speech-Recognition Package, I Tried To Make a Button Icon Which Stops onClick When The Mic Was Off or Turns on When Earlier it Was off

I Tried a Lot To Fix the Issue,
here's My Code.

```
import React, { Component, useRef } from "react";
import firebase from "../firebase";
import { createSpeechlySpeechRecognition } from "@speechly/speech-recognition-polyfill";
import SpeechRecognition, {
  useSpeechRecognition,
} from "react-speech-recognition";
var axios = require("axios").default;

export default function Chat() {
  let messages = [{ main: "Hey there! Wassop", class: "left" }];
  let messageRef = useRef();
  const appId = "I_HAVE_MY_KEY_HERE";
  const SpeechlySpeechRecognition = createSpeechlySpeechRecognition(appId);
  SpeechRecognition.applyPolyfill(SpeechlySpeechRecognition);

  const {
    transcript,
    listening,
    browserSupportsSpeechRecognition,
    isMicrophoneAvailable,
  } = useSpeechRecognition();
  const startListening = () =>
    SpeechRecognition.startListening({ continuous: true });

  function Mic() {
    if (listening) {
        return SpeechRecognition.stopListening()
    } else {
        return SpeechRecognition.abortListening()
      }    
  }
  function onSend(e) {
    let message = messageRef.current.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML +=
      "<div class='right'>" + message + "</div>";
    if (message == "") {
      alert("Field shall not be empty!");
    }
    var options = {
      ---API REQUEST----
    };
    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        messageRef.current.value = "";
        messages.push({
          main: response.data.cnt,
          class: "left",
        });
        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML +=
          "<div class='left'>" + response.data.cnt + "</div>";
        console.log(messages);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h1 className="text-2xl text-center font-bold">Chat Box</h1>
      <p>Microphone: {listening ? "on" : "off"}</p>
      <p>{transcript}</p>
      <br />
      <div id="messages">
        {messages.map((message) => (
          <div key={message.main} className={message.class}>
            {message.main}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <br />
      <form onSubmit={onSend}>
        <div class="relative flex w-2/4 flex-wrap items-stretch mb-3">
          <span class="z-10 h-full leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-blueGray-300 absolute bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 pl-3 py-3">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-flatart-icons-flat-flatarticons/64/000000/external-message-contact-flatart-icons-flat-flatarticons.png" />
          </span>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={messageRef}
            placeholder="Message"
            class="px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 relative bg-white bg-white rounded text-sm border-0 shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full pl-10"
          />
          <span class="z-10 h-full leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-blueGray-300 absolute bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 right-0 pr-3 py-3 mic">
            <img
              src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/000000/microphone.png"
              onClick={Mic()}
            />
          </span>
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        >
          Button
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I Get The Error Of Too Many Renders Which Im Not Able To Figure Out How To Fix I Tried Loooking a lot But Nothing Helped, Im Not Even Able To Understand Someone Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1):

## Reason for too much re-render

If you are binding your `onClick` functions like this:

```
onClick={Mic()}
```

React will call the function, without the need of an actual click. You should use `onClick={Mic}` or `onClick={() => Mic()}`

## *There are a couple of other issues with your code:*

### 1. Using ref

You are using a `useRef` variable to hold the message`useRef` update will not trigger a re-render. Instead try to use a `useState` hook to bind the variable to a state variable

### 2. Creating the object inside the functional component

You are creating `messages` object inside the functional component. On every re-render, this `messages` object will be initialized to the same array. Bind this to a `state` variable to reflect changes made to the `messages` object.

```
import {useState} from 'react'

const [messages, setMessages] = useState([{ main: "Hey there! Wassop", class: "left" }])
```

### 3. DOM Manipulation

You should avoid DOM manipulation like:

```
document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML +=  "<div class='right'>" + message + "</div>";
```

if possible. You can use `ref`s *in this case* and bind it to the JSX.

```
const messageRef = useRef('')

return(
...
<div id="message" ref={messageRef}> ...
...
)
```

I will strongly suggest reading more about React lifecycle and hooks:

## [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)

Comment: I Changed It But It Still Didnt Work. Doesnt Start Listening

Comment: The question is about unnecessary re-renders, I don't know why your Mic() function doesn't work as intended. The solution should fix the problem asked in the question.